# Hash a string with Batch and Catching variable from file of specific line

Tags: variables, hash, batch-file, cmd, line

Is it possible to hash variable, something like `sha1($var);` or `md5($var);` in PHP, but then in Batch.

Is it possible to get variable from specific line of file? `set variable=<textfile.txt` would be useful, but it takes only first line. Is it possible to take for example 3rd line of code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to "hashing" a variable in PHP. But there are a number of ways to read the nth line of a text file in Windows batch. Here are two methods to extract the 3rd line.

Using FOR /F with skip:

```
for /f skip^=2^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (textfile.txt) do set "var=%%A"&goto break
:break
```

Using SET /P:

```
<textfile.txt (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 2) do set /p "="
  set "var="
  set /p "var="
)
```

Comment: Uhm... you just... overpowered my brain. How can I retrieve data from third like, lets say I need it as variable `var1` from line 4... how I am supposed to do it? I mean to retrieve it like `echo %var1%`.

Comment: @user2037860 - Did you try the code? They both work. Simply append an `echo %var%` to the end of either one to see the result.

Comment: Whoaw, it really works. Thanks... sorry for testing it just now.